# Reading Input till User Stops

Tags: python, python-3.x

What if In **Python 3.4** I want to do read values *(here int)* till the user give input.
Like this *C-code*

```
while( scanf("%d", &no) )
    {
     printf("%d" , no);
}
```

I tried something like :

```
inp = input()
while inp != '':
   print(int(inp))
   inp = input()
```

This above python code worked as long as I input manually from terminal and ended input with *enter or newline*

But it throw : **EOFError: EOF when reading a line** when i read from the  stdin in linux terminal using:

```
python3.4 filename.py < input
```

if the *input* file don't contain a trailing *newline*.

#### Edit:

Am using this method now, and waiting for some other ways.

```
 import sys

 for line in sys.stdin:
     do_anything()   #here reading input
 # End here
 else_whatever()     #just passing here
```

Comment: Well are you reading user input or are you reading from a file? Those are two completely different operations. Also, where's the code that throws the `EOFError`?

Comment: the above python part of my post throw that error

Comment: You said it throws `EOFError` when you read from a file. You don't have any code in your question reading from a file.

Comment: add the traceback, are you running it as a script when it errors?

Comment: OP is piping a file to stdin. You can also get an `EOFError` if you `Ctrl+D`.

Comment: is it making sense after the edit sir? @Two-BitAlchemist

Comment: @SagarKar Yep. I'm not sure what to tell you. `input` reads till the newline because that's how most input works. You have to either match the file contents to the expected input or use a different method of collecting input.

Comment: [fileinput.input()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html)

Comment: @dawg That should be the answer. I forgot about that function.

Comment: what i am doing now is `import sys` and `for p in sys.stdin: ` am i doing anything wrong? @Two-BitAlchemist  @Cyphase

Comment: can i know the reason for the down-vote? so that i can try not making it again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat input.txt
hello
```

Try using [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html) like so:

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line)
```

Test it:

```
$ python3 input.py < input.txt
hello
```

Fileinput is also smart smart enough to distinguish between a file name and stdin:

```
$ python3 input.py input.txt
hello
```

Comment: actually i was wrong saying i want to input from file! i want it both ways! Do the edit make sense ?

Comment: `fileinput` supports both a file name or text from stdin (Perl and awk like functionality...)

Comment: ok i shall research about that.... i am accepting the ans but will surely look for other ways of doing it... preferably without importing something .... bdw thanks for ur ans!

Comment: You cannot read stdin without importing something.  Both `sys` and `fileinput` are in the standard distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Just catch the error..

```
def safe_input(prompt=None):
    try:
        return input(prompt)
    except EOFError:
        return ''

inp = safe_input()
while inp != '':
   print(int(inp))
   inp = safe_input()
```